# React: AppStore listener must be a function(Flux Facebook)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: listener must be a function"
I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have spend lot of time on this, but not getting anywhere.

```
  var AppStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {

      emitChange: function () {
          this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
     },

       addChangeListener: function(callback){

        this.on(CHANGE_EVENT,callback);

      }

   });

AppDispatcher.register(function (callback) {
    //console.log(username);
    //console.log(password);
    var action = callback.action;

    //var test = AppStore.addChangeListener(callback);
    //console.log(test);

    switch(action.actionType) {
        case AppConstants.ADD_ITEM:
            _addItem(callback.action.item);
            break;
    }
    return true;

});
```

My component look like this

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // Called after react has rendered the HTML in the DOM.
    AppStore.addChangeListener(this.handleChange);
    console.log(AppStore.addChangeListener(this.handleChange));
  }

    handleChange() {
    debugger;
    this.forceUpdate();
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried binding the callback? this.handleChange.bind(this)

Comment: Can you show use your handleChange function

Comment: No its not working @PavelStaselun

Comment: hey @oliv37 i am just learning flux, so i used it from some tutorial as they have used. i thought its define by flux may be.

Comment: @oliv37 its not define by me, anywhere in code.

Comment: basically i am trying to bring my data from AppStore to components.... if you know about, please guide  me.

Comment: basically **this.handleChange** seems to not be a function

Comment: yes.. now i am looking for it and thinking of declare of this function

Comment: can you help me through teamviewer.. i am really stuck on it for 2 days.

Comment: handle change function is now declared

Comment: You should use `this.handleChange.bind(this)` anyway, because inside you use `this`, which otherwise would be set to object in which context the callback is being run.

Comment: thanks.. thats the solution..

Comment: if you write it, i will accept your answer..